# iOS framework addition failed due to a CocoaPods installation failure error since SDK update

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, cocoapods

Since I have updated the IronSource SDK version, this error happens every time I try to get a build for IOS.

```
OS framework addition failed due to a CocoaPods installation failure. 
This will will likely result in an non-functional Xcode project.

After the failure, "pod repo update" was executed and succeeded. "pod install" was then attempted again, and still failed. This may be due to a broken CocoaPods installation. See: https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/troubleshooting.html for potential solutions.

pod install output:

Analyzing dependencies
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "IronSourceSDK":
  In Podfile:
    IronSourceAdMobAdapter (= 4.3.22.0) was resolved to 4.3.22.0, which depends on
      IronSourceSDK (= 7.1.5.0)

    IronSourceSDK (= 7.1.5.1)

Specs satisfying the `IronSourceSDK (= 7.1.5.1), IronSourceSDK (= 7.1.5.0)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

You can also check out the screenshot:
[error log from unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jy5E6.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If somebody faces this issue in the future, note that in this line, it says both versions `7.1.5.1` and `7.1.5.0` can be resolved, but the system needs to know which one should be used:

```
Specs satisfying the `IronSourceSDK (= 7.1.5.1), IronSourceSDK (= 7.1.5.0)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

So, try to identify if you still need to upgrade or downgrade the SDK to one of the versions mentioned in the error.

For you it was about: `IronSourceSDK`, but it could be any other. In my case, it was complaining about the `FBAudienceNetwork`:

```
Specs satisfying the `FBAudienceNetwork (= 6.8.0), FBAudienceNetwork (= 6.9.0)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

So I needed to upgrade the `FBAudienceNetwork` to `6.9.0`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by removing all ironSource and External Dependancy Manager files and reinstalling the latest version from the website instead of updating via the integration manager.